# Spring Annotations - I am getting some documents regarding Annotaions

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Spring Annotations - I am getting some documents regarding Annotations but, they are explaining each annotation and how to use it. 
but i want, know how can achieve same annotations behavior with bean configuration.
ex:

```
Annotation            Bean config
@Required               ?
```

Can you help.................

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but here are some links from the [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html) that seem relevant:

- [3.9. Annotation-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)
- [3.11. Java-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)

---

On second thought (and after editing your question's source) I seem to understand. I think you want an XML alternative to the `@Required` annotation.

Quote from [the `@Required` section](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-required-annotation):

> The container throws an exception if the affected bean property has not been populated; this allows for eager and explicit failure, avoiding NullPointerExceptions or the like later on.

I'm not sure such a thing exists in XML, I think the only way to get that behavior is through explicit wiring.

```
<bean class"foo.bar.Service.class">
    <!-- This will fail if no bean named subService is available -->
    <property name="subService" ref="subService" />
</bean>
```